# Why are ^ and $ still magic in nomagic mode?

Tags: regular-expression, options, history-of

In 'nomagic' mode, `^` and `$` have a special meaning and no others do. Why were these selected, rather than making people type `\^` and `\$` just as they do for `\.` and `\*`?

EDIT: I have been able to confirm that this behavior, and the magic option, goes back to ex version 1.1 ([regex implementation](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=1BSD/ex-1.1/ex_re.c), [options](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=1BSD/ex-1.1/ex_set.c)). The structure also suggests an answer for `^`: It is handled specially outside the main loop.

Answer (score 5):

The `nomagic` setting was created to support the `edit` mode, which was "designed for more casual or beginning users", rather than as a general "nothing is a metacharacter" mode.

[From the ex reference manual](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=1BSD/exrefm/exrefma.n):

> The *ex* default setting of *magic* gives quick access to a powerful set of regular expression metacharacters. The disadvantage of *magic* is that the user must remember that these metacharacters are *magic* and precede them with the character '\' to use them as "ordinary" characters. With *nomagic*, the default for *edit*, regular expressions are much simpler, there being only two metacharacters. The power of the other metacharacters is still available by preceding the (now) ordinary character with a '\'. Note that '\' is thus always a metacharacter.
>
> The remainder of the discussion of regular expressions assumes that that the setting of this option is *magic*. To discern what is true with *nomagic* it suffices to remember that the only special characters in this case will be '^' at the beginning of a regular expression, '$' at the end of a regular expression, and '\'.

When started as `edit`, ex 1.1 sets `noopen` (not permitted to enter visual mode), `nomagic`, and `notify=1` (ex default is 5, `notify` is equivalent to vim `report`).

The `nomagic` setting also affects the usage of `&` and `~` in substitution commands.

(Still no idea why, but we'd probably have to ask someone who was at Berkeley in the '70s for that.)

Comment: Thanks for writing this up! When the pdf manual I found didn't format text correctly, I gave up on quoting it directly without thinking to just search for another version

Comment: @MattBoehm Firefox's built-in PDF viewer has problems with copy and paste in my experience; have you tried opening it in Acrobat Reader? And I formatted this by hand from the source; I didn't see the PDF you found.

Comment: Things were messed up enough that I think the PDF was generated from an OCR scan, but I'll try acrobat in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently magic/nomagic dates back to Ex (mentioned in the [pdf user manual](http://roguelife.org/~fujita/COOKIES/HISTORY/1BSD/exrefm.pdf)), but I'm not sure of the reasoning behind the original decision. If you're using Vim, there are 4 levels of 'magic' you can use. The two additional modes are explained in [`:help /magic`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2Fmagic):

```
Use of "\v" means that in the pattern after it all ASCII characters except
'0'-'9', 'a'-'z', 'A'-'Z' and '_' have a special meaning.  "very magic"

Use of "\V" means that in the pattern after it only the backslash has a
special meaning.  "very nomagic"
```

This at least seems to have some logic to it. If you want no characters to have special meaning besides `\` in Vim, you can start your pattern with `\V`

Comment: I don't think "very" mode existed in vi. And `\V` seem to have been created explicitly because nomagic/`\M` does not do this.

Comment: Correct, I'll edit my query to mention that this is vim-specific